# Command produces different results in commandline versus script file

Tags: linux, ksh

I have this line

```
grep -n -m7 '\$' myfile.asm | tail -n 1 | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
```

Which produces this output:

```
27
```

I wanted to use it in a script that is editing a file.  So I did this in `myscript.ksh`:

```
fileName=$1
....
lastLine=`grep -n -m7 '\$' ${fileName}.asm | tail -n 1 | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`
....
echo ${lastLine}
```

When I do this the expected value of `27` in `lastLine` is only `7`.  Here is first 30 lines of the file I'm working with.

```
$***********************************************************************
$ THE FOLLOWING BULK DATA ENTRIES RELATED TO EXT. SUPERELEMENT     5000
$ ARE FOR USE IN THE MAIN BULK DATA PORTION OF THE ASSEMBLY RUN
$***********************************************************************
$
SEBULK      5000EXTOP2            MANUAL                      12
$
SECONCT     5000       0              NO
           60582   60582  180021  180021  180023  180023  180057  180057
          180941  180941  180942  180942  180943  180943  180944  180944
          180946  180946  180947  180947  204499  204499  231050  231050
          231060  231060  232050  232050  232060  232060  252300  252300
          252301  252301  253072  253072  253073  253073  401101  401101
          401102  401102  401103  401103  401104  401104  402101  402101
          402102  402102  402103  402103  402104  402104  403101  403101
          403102  403102  403103  403103  403104  403104  404101  404101
          404102  404102  404103  404103  404104  404104  405101  405101
          405102  405102  405103  405103  405104  405104  406101  406101
          406102  406102  406103  406103  406104  406104  407101  407101
          407102  407102  407103  407103  407104  407104  408101  408101
          408102  408102  408103  408103  408104  408104  631050  631050
          631060  631060  632050  632050  632060  632060  652300  652300
          652301  652301  653072  653072  653073  653073  662050  662050
          662060  662060  677500  677500  677600  677600  678516  678516
          678622  678622  679514  679514  679620  679620  703077  703077
          703078  703078 1184100 1184100 1184200 1184200 1184400 1184400
$
CORD2C*           220102          220104 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00
*        0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00 0.100000000E+01
*        0.100000000E+01 0.900000000E+02 0.100000000E+01
```

What I am trying to do is copy the SECONCT entry out of this file into another at this stage.  I know it begins with `SECONCT` and ends with the 7th `$`.  Like I said it works at the command line but not in the script.  If I use the "`" operator at the command line I get this error:

> -ksh: 7: not found [No such file or directory]

So this is related to that operator but I've never had this problem before.  How do I fix it?

Update: 
I ran it with `set -x` here is the output:

```
+ grep -n -m7 '$' sq93a3mkop2_4hz.asm
+ awk -F: '{print $1}'
+ tail -n 1
+ lastLine=7
```

The error is from the `\$` being read in as `$`.  But how do I fix that?

Comment: To debug shell scripts, put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see all the commands being executed, with all the variables filled in. This usually helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

This is a much simpler way to output that section:

```
 sed -n '/SECONCT/,/^\$$/p' myfile.asm
```

I don't have ksh installed, but this works under csh.

Explanation:

- "-n" - sed will only print what you are interested in.
- "/SECONCT/" - Start when the SECONCT line appears.
- "/^\$$/" - Stop when the next line with just "$" appears.
- "p" - Print everything between the two patterns, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks I most certainly was over complicating things.  This is how I learn.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `` `backticks` ``. Use `$(..)` instead:

```
lastLine=$(grep -n -m7 '\$' ${fileName}.asm | tail -n 1 | awk -F':' '{print $1}')
```

Backticks are legacy syntax with several quirks, one of which is imposing a new layer of special escapes of certain characters:

```
$ echo '\$'
\$

$ echo "`echo '\$'`"    # Working command produces different results in backticks
$

$ echo "`echo '\\$'`"   # ... and requires another layer of escaping.
\$

$ echo "$(echo '\$')"   # $() just works.
\$
```

Modern command substitution, `$(..)`, does not have these issues and lets you wrap unmodified commands. `$(..)` is POSIX, so there's no reason to ever use backticks.